# FlatList scrollToIndex out of range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a FlatList where I'm trying to scroll through each index of my data array every X amount of seconds. There's only two items in my array right now but there could be more. The current code works for the first two iterations but then it does not seem to reset properly and I get the `scrollToIndex out of range error: index is 2 but maximum is 1`. I would think that when the `currentIndex` is `>= data.length` my `if` statement would `setCurrentIndex` back to 0 but it doesn't seem to work. Basically what I'm trying to do is loop the items in the Flatlist automatically but each item pausing for a few seconds.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React,  {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator, HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
  PanResponder,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

import { Immersive } from 'react-native-immersive';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import WineList from './screens/WineList';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Rate from './screens/Rate';
import Thankyou from './screens/Thankyou';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const { width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");

const wineclub = require('./images/wineclub.png');
const gaspers = require('./images/gaspers.png');
const qrcode = require('./images/wineclubQR.png');

let ads = [
  {
    adImg: wineclub,
    adTitle: 'Space will be limited so join online today!',
    adInfo: ' Upon joining, both clubs will be billed our Trio Pre-Opening Promotion',
    qrCodeImg: qrcode
  },
  {
    adImg: gaspers,
    adTitle: 'Coming Soon!',
    adInfo: 'Gourmet chef designed menu. Stunning views. Modern romantic decor',
    qrCodeImg: qrcode
  }
]


function AdSlider({data}){
    
  return(
   
             <View style={{alignContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:'#4B4239', height:1400}}>

               <Image source={data.adImg} style={{width:640,height:500}} ></Image>

               <Text style={{color:'white', fontFamily:'LaoMN', fontSize:30, marginTop:20}}>{data.adTitle}</Text>

               <Text style={{color:'white', fontFamily:'LaoMN', fontSize:20, marginTop:20, textAlign:'center'}} > {data.adInfo} </Text>

               

               <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'flex-start', alignContent:'center', alignItems:'center', marginTop:20}}>
                 <Text style={{fontSize:40, color:'white', padding:20}}>Scan Here </Text>

                 <Image source={data.qrCodeImg}></Image>
               </View>

             </View>
            
  )
}

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  Immersive.on()
  Immersive.setImmersive(true)

  const navigationRef = useRef(null);

    
  const myRef = useRef(null);   

  const currentIndex = useRef(0);

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const timerId = useRef(false);

  const [timeForInactivityInSecond, setTimeForInactivityInSecond] = useState(
    5
  )

 

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInactivityTimeout()
  },[])

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
        // console.log('user starts touch');
        
        setModalVisible(false)
        resetInactivityTimeout()
      },
    })
  ).current

  const resetInactivityTimeout = () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId.current)
    
    timerId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      // action after user has been detected idle
      
      setModalVisible(true)
      navigationRef.current?.navigate('Home');
    }, timeForInactivityInSecond * 1000)
  }

 
// for the slider
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      currentIndex.current = currentIndex.current === ads.length - 1
        ? 0
        : currentIndex.current + 1;
        myRef.current.scrollToIndex({
          animated: true,
          index: currentIndex.current ,
        });
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);
  

  

  return (
    
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} >
       <View {...panResponder.panHandlers}  style={{ flex:1}}>

         <TouchableWithoutFeedback >
       <Modal
             
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={false}
            hardwareAccelerated={false}
            visible={modalVisible}
      
            >
              <FlatList
              ref={myRef}
              data={ads}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return <AdSlider key={index} data={item} dataLength={ads.length} />;
              }}
              pagingEnabled
              horizontal
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}

              />
             
              
            </Modal>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <Stack.Navigator navigationOptions={{headerTintColor: '#ffffff',}} screenOptions={{
           headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#4B4239' },
          }} >
          <Stack.Screen name="Home"
          component={Home}  options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }} />  

          <Stack.Screen name="WineList" component={WineList} options={{
          title: 'Exit',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#4B4239',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}/>

          <Stack.Screen name="Rate" component={Rate} options={{
          title: 'Back to Selections',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#4B4239',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}/>

          <Stack.Screen name="Thankyou" component={Thankyou} 
          options={
          {  
          headerShown: false,    
          title: 'Home',  
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#4B4239',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>    
    </View>
      </NavigationContainer>

  );
};



export default App;
```

Comment: The first 2 lines do not seem to belong to a component. useState, and useRef, must be used at the beginning of a component.

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the full code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are passing the `item` as `data` to the `AdSlider` component and it does not have any `length` property of course thus it returns `undefined` for `data.length` and that does not evaluate the expression `currentIndex === data.length - 1` which it becomes `currentIndex === undefined - 1` thus `currentIndex` will get increased by `1` without stopping and it will reach the value of `2` which is out of bounds.

There are several issues with your code.

1. You should not have a component inside another component and especially not when using effects and state from the parent component. Remove `AdSlider` outside of the `App` component.
2. You are passing item as `data` to the `AdSlider` and you are trying to fetch that as the `data.length`, which is obvious that it's not going to work because the `data` is the `item` which is an object and not an array.
3. You don't need to use the effects inside the `AdSlider`, set just one effect inside the `App` and change `currentIndex` to be a ref instead of a state variable because you don't need it's changing state in order to re-render because you're calling `scrollToIndex` for forcing the list to update and re-render.

### Making it work using state and `setTimeout`

If you want to make the code wotk with `currentIndex` being in state (*which you don't need*), you can move effects inside the `App` component and change `data.length` with `ads.length` and it will work.

```js
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  Immersive.on()
  Immersive.setImmersive(true)

  const navigationRef = useRef(null);
  const myRef = useRef(null);   
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.scrollToIndex({
      animated: true,
      index: currentIndex ,
    });
  }, [currentIndex]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const timer = setTimeout(()=> {
      // Change data.length to ads.length here
      const nextIndex = currentIndex === ads.length - 1
        ? 0
        : currentIndex + 1;
      setCurrentIndex(nextIndex);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [currentIndex]);

  ...
}
```

### Making it work using ref and `setInterval`

Best thing to do though, is to convert `currentIndex` to a be a ref and use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` to have a looping timer call every 5 seconds:

```js
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  Immersive.on()
  Immersive.setImmersive(true)

  const navigationRef = useRef(null);
  const myRef = useRef(null);   
  // Make currentIndex a ref instead of a state variable,
  // because we don't need the re-renders
  // nor to trigger any effects depending on it
  const currentIndex = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Have a timer call the function every 5 seconds using setInterval
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      // Change data.length to ads.length here
      currentIndex.current = currentIndex.current === ads.length - 1
        ? 0
        : currentIndex.current + 1;
      myRef.current.scrollToIndex({
        animated: true,
        index: currentIndex.current,
      });
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  ...
}
```

You can check a working Expo Snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/@clytras/flatlist-scrolltoindex-out-of-range).

Comment: Well this seems to work but the app crashes for a bit and then it gives this error: `null is not an object(evaluating 'myRef.current.scrollToIndex')`. I updated my post to reflect the new changes.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct. I think the modal `panResponder` code that I introduced is causing another issue now with the error I'm getting now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. The error `null is not an object(evaluating 'myRef.current.scrollToIndex')` is most likely happening because of fast refresh (*or hot reload*) and the effect get to trigger before `myRef` gets the actual list reference, thus it's null the first time it's called after a rerender. You either check `myRef.current` if it's not falsy, or even better use optional chaining to call `scrollToIndex` like this `myRef?.current?.scrollToIndex(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

looks like your `if` statement is incorrect, the maximum index should be `totalLength - 1`.
for example, we have an array of 3 items: `[{id: 1, index: 0}, {id: 2, index: 1}, {id: 3, index: 2}]`, then the length of the array is `3`, but the maximum index is `2`, so when the current index is ">= 2 (totalLength - 1)", you should reset it to `0`. and for the else conditions, set next index to 'currentIdx + 1'

```js
      if(activeIdx === ITEMS.length - 1){
        setActiveIdx(0)
      } else {
        setActiveIdx(idx => idx + 1);
      }
```

for more detailed, code may look like this:

```
function Slider(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = React.useState(0)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.scroll({left: ITEM_WIDTH * activeIdx, behavior: "smooth"}) // please use .scrollToIndex here
  }, [activeIdx]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      let nextIdx = activeIdx === ITEMS.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIdx + 1;
      setActiveIdx(nextIdx)
    }, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [activeIdx]);

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but I still get the `scrollToIndex out of range: requested index 2 but maximum is 1`. I updated the post with the new code